# Is there a proof about the divisibility of the sum of a sequence of natural numbers raised to the power of some odd natural number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof about the divisibility of the sum of a sequence of natural numbers raised to the power of some odd natural number is divisible by the sum of natural numbers in sequence

Like this $4^n + 5^n + 6^n$ is divisible by $15$ where $n$ is odd integer

Answer (score 3):

Pair the terms up in reverse (in the even case) 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{2k} (j+i) = \cdots+ (j+i) + \cdots + (j+2k-i)+ \cdots = k(2k+2j).
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{2k} (j+i)^{2n+1}  = \cdots+ (j+i)^{2n+1} + \cdots + (j+2k-i)^{2n+1}+ \cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}
These terms will factorise
\begin{eqnarray*}
&(j+i)^{2n+1} +  (j+2k-i) ^{2n+1} \\ &= \color{red}{( (j+i) +  (j+2k-i)  ) }( (j+i)^{2n}  - \cdots +  (j+2k-i) ^{2n}).
\end{eqnarray*}
A similar argument will work for an odd number of terms.

Comment: Almost there :-)

Comment: Can you explain this more clearly I couldn't understand this for odd numbers.